# show items in a list like email

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

how do I display a list of items on the screen, like how email is displayed on the screen?

[image]

What is this controller called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a UITableView. Check the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) and [Table View Suite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) code sample by apple.

Comment: UITableViewController to be specific ;-) The view is called UITableView.